# Android emulator disconnect issue

Tags: android

I have an android project. And I am using eclipse with android Virtual machine, When i run my project, i get the following error

emulator-5554 disconnected! Cancelling 'pk.edu.pucit.mc.surfaceviewdemo.MainActivity activity launch'!

Do any one know why this error comes ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try to reset adb

[image]

hope this helps!